# Error in assigning temporary location while creating a job from template (Cloud dataflow) in google cloud platform

Tags: templates, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a dataflow pipeline using dataflow template in GCP. I am getting error in assigning temporary location while creating a job from template in dataflow.
The error line is mentioned below:

```
Value must be of a GCS path form: "gs://<bucket>/path/[optional-path]"
```

The screenshot of the tab is given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK4qY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure the problem is you have brackets (<>) around the name of the bucket.

Try:

`gs://qwiklabs-gcp-00-22dff2300e09/tmp`

Comment: Thank you so much Gabe Weiss. This solved my problem.

Comment: NP! Please accept the answer too so it's more searchable. :)